# Segmentation fault on mov instruction x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm having some trouble with a line of code, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it. This is for a simple program in my CSE class using assembly. For this part, I am supposed to calculate x^2 (where x is a value originally stored in %rdi). Here is the code segment that is giving me trouble:

```
    movq %rdi, %rax     
    imulq %rdi                  # %rax = %rdi * %rax = x^2
    movq %rax, %r10             # %r10 = x^2
    movq (%r10,%r10,4), %r11    # SEG FAULT OCCURS HERE 
                                # %r11 = x^2 + 4 * x^2 = 5x^2
```

As a note, I need x^2 to be in all of these registers for reasons outside of the code I am sharing.

I ran this code through the debugger, and %rdi, %rax, and %r10 all have x^2 stored in them. So why would the last line return a seg fault error?

Comment: Your `mov` is using `5 * x^2` as an address to load from.  It looks like you meant to use LEA.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Changed it to leaq and it works fine, now. Many thanks!